# How to get notifications when app is in close mode?

Tags: codenameone

Notifications are currently displaying when the installed app is opened or minimized. Can we display this notifications when app is in close mode.

Do I need any configurations or code changes required to handle this requirement?

Comment: Push notifications supposed to show when an app is closed or minimized. On what device are you experiencing this and what Push Type are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Background notifications work when the app is closed and minimized, that is their purpose. Make sure you followed the instructions in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html) when setting them up.